# WKWebView White Screen (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, webkit, wkwebview

Still having some trouble with Webkit. After sorting out my error from yesterday morning, I have encountered a whole new slue of them ranging from 113 to straight up crashes (really new to iOS dev, formally trained in C++ and very rusty haha).

I've finally got some code that doesn't crash and I feel like I'm definitely getting a better grasp on Objective-C/iOS Dev in general - there's just one issue... It doesn't load.

WebView.h

```
#ifndef WebView_h
#define WebView_h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Webkit/Webkit.h>

@interface ViewController: UIViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *view;
@end 
#endif WebView_h
```

WebView.m

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.penelopeperu.com/"];
    NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:urlReq];
    self.view = webView; 
}
@end
```

I suspect it has something to do with the view / UIView and loading? I'm just not sure how to pinpoint what I'm doing wrong exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url is not using "https" security protocol, so you need to add following key in Info.plist file to allow load your url in web view.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Also you are doing one more wrong thing with webview.

This doesen't proper way to add `webview` in `self.view`.

```
self.view = webView;
```

updated this line with;

```
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've made those changes, however I'm still only seeing a white screen. EDIT: The page was just taking awhile to load, nevermind. All fixed. Thank you again!

Comment: @bbug333, Happy to help you.